# Any tool to autogenerate View Models from Entity Framework Domain Models?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC3, ASP.NET 4.5, C#, MSSQL.

I need to create ViewModels from my Domain Model that is automatically generated by Entity Developer.

Once I create the relevant ViewModel for an entity I can comment out non required properties for a particular View.

However there is the ongoing concern that once an entity is upgraded then the ViewModel could become out of sync, and I want to minimise the risk/effort in fixing this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What would the tool generate? Only you know what you want your view models need to do.

Comment: In the first instance it would be a copy of the entity class which one could then strip down for the View in question. Copy and Paste is certainly the immediate answer I guess !!

Comment: The other interesting factor with this is that validation, in my case is stored in the Domain model, so validation annotations are in the class definitions. If I missed these off the ViewModels, and then automapped from ViewModel to DomainModel, then this validation could be interrupted. Thus I believe these annotations need to be on the ViewModel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see the same complaint endlessly about using view models. True, they can be repetitive in nature, but copy and paste works beautifully there. If you so wanted, you could even design an interface that both your model and view model must implement, which can help you keep the two in sync somewhat. However, I think you'll find that the two will diverge more than you think.

As far as validation goes, this is also a common complaint, but it's actually a symptom of bad design. Your entity class should only have validation specific to the database, which you'll find is actually pretty sparse. Entity Framework actually does a fantastic job translating most of the properties inherent limitations to the database. For example, a `DateTime` property's column is set as NOT NULL by default, because the C# type itself cannot be null. There's no need to add something like `[Required]`, because the behavior is inherent.

Other types of validations such as regex are totally inappropriate for a domain model because there's no correlation to anything happening at the database level. It's entirely for the UI, and thus belongs on your view model. I think you'll find that if you evaluate all the things you're trying to validate on your domain model, you'll find most if not all should be strictly on your view model(s) instead.

Comment: Huge thanks for the comprehensive answer. I would like to raise a question regarding validation. If say RestockLevel is on an OrderItem record, then surely one would want the relevant validation against the domain property once, rather than multiple time across multiple ViewModels. So I am minded to keep validation closer to the data or business entity. Is this not correct?

Comment: You're looking at the wrong way. First, if the validation only happens after you map your data from view model to entity, you're going to have problems. Second, if your concern is repeating the validation, the solution is to abstract it way into a custom validation attribute or something, so that each view model can use the same validation. It's not an argument for keeping validation that's not part of the domain as part of the domain.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your valuable insight.